# Print text of xpath of element in Python

Tags: android, python, xpath, webdriver

I need to print text of xpath, which is:

```
def imageOrVideo(self):
    try:
        # camera1 = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.eightdevelopment.eas.android:id/video_view')
        # source_code = camera1.get_attribute("class")
        camera1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.VideoView[1]')
        print(camera1)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Status Not Visible!")
        return False
```

I tried to print class text itself or xpath text, but always get some weird outcome.
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Could be useful to see this weird output. Anyway if your xpath is correct you get a webdriver element (camera1). So if you want to show element text you need to use text property. Try: print camera1.text

Comment: thank you, the problem is - the text is black line. So i need to find out a way how to print out xpath itself without a text

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get xpath from WebElement Object.  However, as you are using python you can achieve this by monkeypatching webdriver `find_element` method to store the value in some property which you can retrieve later on.